# Heroku multi-app configuration

Tags: php, ruby, heroku

These days I am experimenting with Heroku server. One of the obstacle I came around, is to deploy 2 different apps; one in Ruby and other in PHP on same free `dyno`. Although I have different directories for both apps like `/support` (for Ruby) and `/support/billing` (for PHP). But I have no idea how to include another web process that will run PHP app from `/support/billing` because in Heroku documentation its mentioned:

> The web process type is special as it’s the only process type that will receive HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. Other process types can be named arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't run two web app on free Heroku dyno (I'm not really sure about paid dynos as well). By the way, you have already answered your question:

> The web process type is special as it’s the **ONLY** process type that
>   will receive HTTP traffic from Heroku’s routers. Other process types
>   can be named arbitrarily.

So at the same time you can't run two web processes for Ruby and PHP apps accordingly so you can't achieve "multi-app configuration" on Heroku free dyno.

Comment: seems like have to create separate dyno for both apps. Right?

Comment: Yes. You have to use separated dynos for it